# Stack variable allocation for char vs char array: Why is there a difference?

Tags: c, gcc

This simple program that prints out the address of two variables:

```
int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
   float My_Float = 10.5;
   char  c;

   printf("addr of My_float is %p\naddr of        c is %p\n", &My_Float, &c);
}
```

outputs, as expected:

```
addr of My_float is 0x7fff52a7eafc
addr of        c is 0x7fff52a7eafb
```

However, this one (with the only difference of char array instead of char) has a different address for "c".

```
int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
   float My_Float = 10.5;
   char  c[20];

   printf("addr of My_float is %p\naddr of        c is %p\n", &My_Float, &c);
}

addr of My_float is 0x7fff5b922adc
addr of        c is 0x7fff5b922af0
```

Why is 'c' allocated at a different position now? More interestingly why is it that 'c' is allocated *after* 'My_Float', considering that the stack grows downward- I expected 'c' to always have an address less than that of 'My_Float' as in the case of the 1st program.

I'm running GCC on a mac with a x86 processer.

Comment: Compiler is free to allocate the variables in any order it likes. C imposes no restriction on it.

Comment: The nasty side-effects of the UB that results from a stack buffer overflow are minimized by putting the array at the start of the stack frame.  No other variables will be overwritten, like a for-loop variable that could cause the program to hang, and it is closest to the canary that detects the overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Sourav Ghosh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2173917/sourav-ghosh) said, compilers are free to reorder variables NOT in a structure. There are a number of reasons this can happen:

- Memory alignment restrictions. Ordering variables from the most restricted to the least restricted reduces wasted gaps in memory. Most data types are restricted to what addresses they can start at. Example: chars can be anything, addresses of short integers (int16) often have to be even. Addresses of int32 often must be evenly divisible by 4. Pointers tend to fall into the most restricted category making big differences between `char c` and `char *ptr`.

  Compiler may order things to reduce common problems if the program has bugs. [Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant) addressed this. UB is Undefined Behavior.

  Mysterious: usually related to optimizations or quirks of hardware behaviors or compiler writers.

Comment: If you want to experiment, reverse the float/char definition and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

For any variables memory allocation can be **Up grawing stack** or **Down growing stack**. It depends on architecture. but **Memory allocation for Array is always Up growing stack**.